# Kubernetes rename cluster

Tags: kubernetes

New to Kubernetes.  How do I rename the cluster after kubeadm init.  The default cluster name is kubenetes and I want to rename it to something more meaningful.  Searched all around and can not find any instructions.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you can read [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-config/):

> During `kubeadm init`, kubeadm uploads the `ClusterConfiguration`
>   object to your cluster in a ConfigMap called `kubeadm-config` in the
>   `kube-system` namespace. This configuration is then read during
>   `kubeadm join`, `kubeadm reset` and `kubeadm upgrade`. To view this
>   ConfigMap call `kubeadm config view`.

Apart from `kubeadm config view` you can use `kubectl get configmaps -n kube-system kubeadm-config -o yaml` to view this `ConfigMap`.

**You can change your kubernetes cluster name simply by editing** `kubeadm-config` `ConfigMap` using following command:

```
kubectl edit configmaps -n kube-system kubeadm-config
```

change value of `clusterName` field e.g.:

```
clusterName: new-fancy-kubernetes-clustername
```

After saving changes to the file you'll see confirmation of successful edit:

```
configmap/kubeadm-config edited
```

Now you can view your new cluster name using `kubeadm config view` command:

```
# kubeadm config view
...
clusterName: new-fancy-kubernetes-clustername
...
```

or this way:

```
# kubectl get configmaps -n kube-system kubeadm-config -o yaml
...
    clusterName: new-fancy-kubernetes-clustername
...
```

---

From `kubectl` perspective your **kubernetes cluster** can be named totally differently than in `kubeadm-config` `ConfigMap`. They are configured independently. Actually in `.kube/config` file you can refer to your **cluster** by any name you want, but you need to make the change both in `clusters` as well as in `contexts` sections. Look at the example below:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: ...
    server: https://10.123.0.2:6443
  name: yet-another-fancy-name
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: yet-another-fancy-name
    user: kubernetes-admin
  name: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
current-context: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin
  user:
    client-certificate-data: ...
```

You may also want to change your context name to reflect the current cluster name, but you don't have to. You can do it just for the sake of consistency:

```
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: yet-another-fancy-name
    user: kubernetes-admin
  name: kubernetes-admin@yet-another-fancy-name
current-context: kubernetes-admin@yet-another-fancy-name
```

Comment: Thanks! The instructions worked.  One more question, Although kubectl get configmap and kubeadm config view all show the new cluster name, the kubectl config get-clusters still shows the default 'kubernetes' as the name.  Is that normal?

Comment: Yes, it's totally normal as changes made in `kubeadm-config ConfigMap` don't affect in any way what you have in config files. I guess you can always update them manually.

Comment: One more thing.  Still don't quite get how to access.  I renamed the default cluster to 'k8'.  
# kubectl config get-contexts
CURRENT   NAME                          CLUSTER      AUTHINFO           NAMESPACE
          kubernetes-admin@kubernetes   kubernetes   kubernetes-admin
*         test                          k8           kubernetes-admin
# kubectl get pods
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

If I switch back to the old default context then everything works.  How do I start to connect using new cluster name?  Thanks!

Comment: From `kubectl` perspective your **kubernetes cluster** can be named totally differently than in `kubeadm-config` `ConfigMap`. They are configured independently. Actually in `.kube/config` file you can refer to your **cluster** by any name you want, but you need to make the change both in `clusters` as well as in `contexts` sections. Please see my edited answer.

Comment: sed -i s/your-old-name/yet-another-fancy-name/ /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf &&
sed -i s/your-old-name/yet-another-fancy-name/ .kube/config

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation where I needed to manage two cluster remotely so I decided to use **kubectx** tool. I am using version 0.9.4 for kubectx.

I created a **.bash_profile** file (I did not have it) and add the **KUBECONFIG** variable pointing to the two config files for my clusters. My clusters were created using **kubeadm** and initially they were created without a specific name. This created a problem when trying to use kubectx, because when I use kubectx it was only showing one cluster.

To solve this, I had to change the name of the context in the context block

```
- context:
    cluster: new-name
    user: kubernetes-admin
  name: kubernetes-admin@new-name
current-context: kubernetes-admin@new-name
```

Then kubectx was able to list my two clusters.